# Start/stop button in Android

Tags: java, android, button

Such a simple thing (hence username) but I just want a start/stop button, it's for a timer but for simplicity we'll go by "starty" and "stoppy" instead of a timer running and a timer not running. I don't want to ask for you to do my code, but if anyone could tell me what I'm missing I'd really love that.

Thanks! :)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            if (helloWorld.getText().length() == 0
                    || helloWorld.equals("stoppy")) {
                helloWorld.setText("starty");
            } else {
                helloWorld.setText("stoppy");
            }
        }
```

Comment: what should we tell you? are you getting any errors?

Comment: What is "helloWorld"? For a very minimal example look at the "Log" documentation for logging while running in the debugger. You could simply switch a state by using a local boolean variable instead of using string comparison.

Comment: @mbanzon i will have to once i make it into a stopwatch, but for now i just needed this to work. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like that

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            if (helloWorld.getText().trim().length() == 0
                    || helloWorld.getText().trim().equals("stoppy")) {
                helloWorld.setText("starty");
            } else {
                helloWorld.setText("stoppy");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a problem..
Add like helloWorld.getText().trim.equals("stoppy") to match the two strings